# ASP.NET Core 6 : filter expression that returns all users with specific claims

Tags: c#, linq, expression, asp.net-core-6.0, claims

I'm creating a web application which has a user-overview list, that offers multiple filtering with a pagination. In the C# backend I'm building a filter expression containing all selected filters. The goal is to dynamically build a queryable that is using this filter expression.

In the frontend it should be possible to check which users have specific claims. Therefore I need to get the claims for each user and check them against the selected filter.

The problem is, that my query is not working, when retrieving the claims inside the expression using the `UserManager`:

```
public async Task<PagedResult<User>> GetUsersAsync(GetAllUsersFilter filter, PaginationFilter paginationFilter)
{
    var queryable = this._dbContext.Users.AsQueryable();
    var filters = GetUserFilterExpression(filter);

    var totalItems = await queryable.Where(filters).CountAsync();

    queryable = queryable.Where(filters);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filter?.OrderColumn))
    {
        queryable = queryable.OrderBy(filter.OrderColumn, filter.OrderType == "desc");
    }

    if (paginationFilter is not null)
    {
        queryable = queryable.Skip((paginationFilter.PageNumber - 1) * paginationFilter.PageSize)
                             .Take(paginationFilter.PageSize);
    }

    var result = await queryable.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

    return new PagedResult<User>
        {
            TotalCount = totalItems,
            ResultSet = result
        };
}

private Expression<Func<User, bool>> GetUserFilterExpression(GetAllUsersFilter queryFilter)
{
    Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter = x => true;

    // queryFilter.Permissions = new List<string> { Permission.Spots.CanEditAkmData };
    if (queryFilter.Permissions is not null && queryFilter.Permissions.Any())
    {
        filter = filter.And(x =>
                queryFilter.Permissions.Intersect(
                    // Get all user claims and concat with ...
                    this._userManager.GetClaimsAsync(x).Result.Select(z => z.Type).Concat(
                    // ... all role claims of the user and distinct the result to make sure that there are no duplicates
                    x.UserRoles.SelectMany(ur => this._roleManager.GetClaimsAsync(ur.Role).Result.Select(uc => uc.Type).ToList())).Distinct()).Any());
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryFilter.Deleted))
    {
        filter = filter.And(x => x.IsDeleted == (queryFilter.Deleted == "true"));
    }

    // other filters are applied here

    return filter;
}
```

I was expecting, that the expression will return all users containing a specific claim but I'm getting this exception:

> The LINQ expression 'ur => ___roleManager_2.GetClaimsAsync(ur.Role).Result
> .AsQueryable()
> .Select(uc => uc.Type)
> .ToList()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: EF Core cannot look into `GetClaimsAsync` method body and translate it to the SQL. Probably you will need to avoid `UserManager` and access to `DbContext` DbSets directly.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I changed my code and used the DBContext, but now I'm facing the exception: 

`Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Core.Domain.Entities.UserClaim]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Core.Domain.Entities.UserClaim]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[System.String] Select[UserClaim,String](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Core.Domain.Entities.UserClaim], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Core.Domain.Entities.UserClaim,System.String]])' (Parameter 'arg0')`

Comment: my filter looks like this now:
                filter = filter.And(x =>
                    queryFilter.Permissions.Intersect(
                        this._dbContext.UserClaims.Where(uc => uc.UserId == x.Id).ToList().Select(z => z.ClaimType)
                            .Concat(
                                this._dbContext.RoleClaims.Where(rc => x.UserRoles.Select(ur => ur.RoleId).Contains(rc.Id)).Select(rc => rc.ClaimType))).Any());

Comment: Better update question.